# passport.deserializeUser not getting called

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

I am currently using passport for authentication. But,the issue i am currently facing is that the passport.deserializeUser doesnt get called , as a result req.isAuthenticated() always return false.

I have read lot of solutions and it doesn't work .

Below is the passport configuration code .

```
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth2").Strategy;
const users = require("./models/Users");

module.exports = function (passport) {
  passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
      {
        clientID: process.env.google_id,
        clientSecret: process.env.secret_key,

        callbackURL: "/auth/login",
        passReqToCallback: true,
      },
      async (request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        const newUser = {
          googleId: profile.id,
          displayName: profile.displayName,
          image: profile.photos[0].value,
        };

        try {
          let user = await users.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });
          console.log("user", user);

          if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            user = await users.create(newUser);
            return done(null, user);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      }
    )
  );

  passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    users.findById(id).exec(function (err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
};
```

Below is the app configuration where passport and express sessions have been initialised.

```
const express_handlebars_1 = require("express-handlebars");
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const tmp = require("express-handlebars");
const path = require("path");
const passport = require("passport");
const session = require("express-session");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const connectDB1 = require("./db_file");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();
dotenv.config({ path: "./.env" });
connectDB1();
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  app.use(morgan("dev"));
}
//static file
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
// session

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "story-book",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { maxAge: 86400000 },
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.db_key }),
  })
);

//passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require("./passport")(passport);

//routes
app.use("/", require("./routes/index"));
app.use("/auth", require("./routes/auth"));
//handlebars
app.engine(".hbs", (0, express_handlebars_1.engine)({ defaultLayout: "main", extname: ".hbs" }));
app.set("view engine", ".hbs");

var port = process.env.PORT;
app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("Server Running in ".concat(process.env.NODE_ENV, " mode under port ").concat(port));
});
```